# Multiple conditions mySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find all the rows that do no contain an of three strings, "Canada","USA" and "United States" and here is what I have

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `Table` 
WHERE 
    `address` LIKE "%United States%" = 0
    OR `address` LIKE "%USA%" = 0
    OR `address` LIKE "%Canada%" = 0
```

So if it has either "Canada" or "United States" or "USA" I don't what it to show up. It works for if there is one like this

```
 SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `Table` 
WHERE 
    `address` LIKE "%United States%" = 0
```

Then I get all that don't have "United states" but it doesn't work with all three?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing `OR` to `AND`?  Also, it's probably easier to read with `NOT LIKE`. . .

Comment: Use the `NOT LIKE` statement for example (WHERE  'address' `NOT LIKE` "%United States%)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think you should use `NOT LIKE` instead of `LIKE = 0`, but the main issue is that you're using an OR for negative conditions, which doesn't give you the result you want. You should use ANDs.

```
WHERE 
`address` NOT LIKE "%United States%"
AND `address` NOT LIKE "%USA%"
AND `address` NOT LIKE "%Canada%"
```

You were getting unexpected results because if that's how OR works. If it matched any of the three cases in your condition, even if it didn't match the other two. So strings with 'USA' in them failed  to match the `LIKE "%USA%"` condition, but they did match the other two, and since at least one of your OR conditions matched, it returned that result.

With AND instead of OR, you should get the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE $targeted_column != '$prohibited_words'